# External stack pipe

Tags: drain-waste-vent, pvc

My friend's house is about 100 years old and the cast soil stack is on the outside. Someone smacked it and there is a crack (with leaking) so we need to replace. Can this be replaced with a PVC or similar plastic pipe? Since we're in the Northeast, should we consider having it moved to an interior wall then through the roof?

Comment: Your vent stack pipe is leaking? Is there waste coming out of it, or just gas?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to repair a damaged cast-iron pipe is with a rubber connector that has two worm drive hose clamps at each end. They come in all types of configurations and diameters. Lasco is a quality brand name as is Fernco. If the break is in the pipe you will have to cut out the damaged section and replace with a similar sized ABS pipe with a rubber connector on each end. Make sure you get the connector appropriate for the repair i.e. cast iron pipe x ABS pipe or cast iron x cast iron. Lube the connectors with dish soap to facilitate installation to pipe. As far as relocating the damaged pipe that's your call, but as you mentioned it's a century old, you truly got your moneys worth. If you're thinking about preventing another accident maybe a protective barrier might be prudent. I've installed 3" galvanized pipe in concrete to prevent similar accidents from damaging gas meters, water lines, etc.